# Задания по javascript

Tags: javascript

Помогите найти задачи по javascript для начинающих, желательно из реальной практики. Спасибо.

Comment: Хороший сборник задач по программированию [http://projecteuler.net/](http://projecteuler.net/)

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru там сначала тема потом задачи по этой теме

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [Современный учебник JavaScript](http://learn.javascript.ru/)
- [Learning Advanced JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/)
- [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html)
- [Javascript Best Practices](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/)

Answer (score 5):

Доброго времени суток!

1. Посмотрите [вакансию
   стажера-разработчика javascript в
   яндекс](http://company.yandex.ru/job/vacancies/trainee_javascript.xml), в конце описания вакансии
   есть задачки для самопроверки.
2. Задачки по основам здесь [jdrupal.ru/node/31](http://jdrupal.ru/node/31).
3. Тесты на [javascript.ru](http://javascript.ru/test).

**UPD**:

Я опубликовал этот ответ два года назад, и сейчас, взглянув на него, понял, что лучшим ответом было бы порекомендовать пройти реальное собеседование. Если вы мечтайте попасть, например, в Яндекс, не обязательно подавать сразу же резюме в Яндекс. Опубликуйте резюме на hh и согласитесь на собеседование с каждым. Так узнаете свои силы, подкачаете их. На собеседовании вам и вопросы зададут, и задачки. За последние три месяца я прошел десяток интервью с крупными российскими компаниями, и скажу честно, прокачал скиллы. Первые два интервью были ужасны, но я записывал вопросы, которые мне задают и прорабатывал их после интервью.

P.S: Я получил работу за границей, в известной компании, а до этого у меня был опыт работы в 1 год, в никому не известной веб студии

Comment: Ты крут, парень. Успехов тебе!